# Why do the endpoints of the radius of convergence $(-e < x < e)$ of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}{x^n}$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to understand why the endpoints of the interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}{x^n}$ diverge...

1. First I found the radius of convergence using:

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}{(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)})^{(n+1)^2}} 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{((1+\frac{1}{-n})^{-n})^{-n}}{((1+\frac{1}{-(n+1)})^{-(n+1)})^{-(n+1)}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^{-n}}{e^{-(n+1)}} \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{e^n}}{\frac{1}{e^{n+1}}} \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{n+1}}{e^n}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e = e = \text{Radius}
\end{align*}$$Therefore, $|x|<\text{Radius}$, that is, $|x|<e = -e < x <e$

2. Then I tried to use the root test of convergence but it resulted inconclusive for $ x = e$: $$\begin{align*}
   ρ =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}{e^n}\right)^{1/n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}{e} \\
   &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{-n}\right)^{-n}\right)^{-1}e\right)\\
   &=\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-1}e = 1,
   \end{align*}$$therefore, the test is inconclusive...
3. I tried using the root test of convergence for $x = -e$ and I got:
   $$\begin{align*}
   ρ =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left((1-\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}{(-e)^n}\right)^{1/n} 
   &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}{(-e)}\right)\\
   &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{-n}\right)^{-n}\right)^{-1}(-e)\right)\\
   &=\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-1}(-e) = -1\end{align*}$$ which I thought converged because $ρ < 1$ but I plugged in the series in wolfram alpha and I found out that it diverged, so I got even more confused...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: For convergence of $\sum a_n$, it is necessary to have $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Test if that's the case with $a_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}e^n$.

Comment: $$
\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)^{n^2 }  = \exp \left( {n^2 \log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {n^2 \left( { - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{{2n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right)} \right)} \right) \\= \exp \left( { - n - \frac{1}{2} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)
$$

Comment: It is known that for a $z$ situated *on* the circle of convergence, you can have convergence or divergence. In the case of divergence, lot of results have been obtained (for example categorizing such points as if some of them where "ordinarily divergent" and others "criticaly divergent") according to the way one can tend to them from inside the disk of convergence...

Comment: For the fun, see the nice Geogebra animation on the final page  [here](https://complex-analysis.com/content/series.html).

Comment: @AnuragA Thank you for your comment! I had forgotten that for convergence it was necessary to have $a_n \rightarrow  0$ when $ n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Gary thank you for your demonstration in Big-O language, really appreciated!

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your comments! I found really interesting the Geogebra animation you attached! :D, thank you for your explanation and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x = e$, note that we have the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \text{ where } a_n := \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} e^n
$$
A known result is that, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \ne 0 $, then the series naturally diverges. You can show that this has limit $1/\sqrt e$, whereas the $x=-e$ will oscillate ever closer to $\pm 1/\sqrt e$.

To find, as an example,
$$
L := \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} e^n
$$
it seems most natural to look at the natural logarithm of it,
$$
\ln(L) := \lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \ln \left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right) + n
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1-\frac 1 n )+\frac 1 n }{\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$
Apply L'Hopital's rule and solve for $L$ to conclude.

---

As a note:

Your error in the third numbered item is a misunderstanding of the root test. To look at the convergence of $\sum a_n$, you will look at
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|
\qquad
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}
$$
for the ratio and root tests, respectively. These absolute values are not superfluous and cannot be dropped unless the terms in a series are all (at least eventually) positive.

The formulas you use to find the radius of convergence are just a specific application of these test to power series, as a further note.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand better which mistakes I made. Your answer couldn't have been better! :D

Comment: Hi again, I was wondering why we look at the limit of the the natural log of $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}(e)^n$ instead of looking at the limit of the original expression? I tried using the nth term test in the original expression for $x = -e$ and I ended up getting $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n$ which doesn't exist in the real world; and when I tried to use it in the original expression for $x= e$ I found that the test was inconclusive, I guess that's why you looked at the limit of the natural log of the original expression instead, but I want to know why we are able to do this trick...

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help, I know you might be very busy, so I really want to thank for your time and help. If you don't have time to review my previous comment, don't worry, I completely understand, but if you do, thanks in advance! :D

Comment: I just chose to look at $\ln(L)$ to find $L$ because, from experience, expressions with the limiting variable in an exponent tend to behave better when you move that exponent down via logarithm properties, and then apply L'Hopital's rule. Note that, if this limit $L$ is anything but zero (whether it be positive, negative, or nonexistent), then the $n$th term test tells you the sum diverges.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I didn't know that the nth-term test was applicable for nonexistent limits! That's interesting! One last question: Is the limit of the natural log of the og expression the same as the limit of the og expression? If it's so, how's that possible? I mean, they're two different expressions, but they're the inverse of the other, so I guess there must be a relation between them because of this inverse relation, right? Thanks in advance for your help! :D  (sorry for bothering you so much, but I really want to undestand as much as possible about this matter)

Comment: The limit is given by $L$. If you know $\ln(L)$, raise it to the power of $e$ to recover $L$. For instance, if you find that $\ln(L)=2$, then the limit is $L=e^2$.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand why you looked at the limit of the natural log, it makes sense! However is this always true? Is the limit of $L$ = $exp(\lim {n \to \infty} Ln(L))$ always true? Can we use this same trick with other types of expressions and their inverses?

Comment: It works a lot of the time, but I'd be hesitant to say it works all of the time. For instance, if the limit is negative, you can't do this (since $\ln(x)$ is undefined for negative numbers).

Comment: Got it! thank you PrincessEev for helping me with all my questions, I really appreciate it. It was wonderful to talk with you. I look forward to seeing you again soon in any of my future questions. See ya! :D